# Search query Elasticsearch with Ngram returns 0 results always

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I use NEST to work with Elasticsearch. I try to break all string fields into tokens. At the same time for tokininiz use ngram. However, when prompting a query, I always get 0 results.

My class to work with api.

```
public class Elasticsearch
{
    string index = "video-materials";
    ElasticClient client;
    public Elasticsearch()
    {
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        if (client.IndexExists(index).Exists)
        {
            client.DeleteIndex(index);
        }
        var nGramFilters = new List<string> { "lowercase", "asciifolding", "nGram_filter" };

        var resp = client.CreateIndex(index, c => c
             .Mappings(m => m
                .Map<ElasticVideoMaterial>(mm => mm
                    .AutoMap()
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.OriginalTitle)
                            .Fields(f => f
                                .Keyword(k => k
                                    .Name("keyword")
                                    .IgnoreAbove(256)
                                )
                                .Text(tt => tt
                                    .Name("ngram")
                                    .Analyzer("ngram_analyzer")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .Analyzers(anz => anz
                        .Custom("ngram_analyzer", cc => cc
                            .Filters(nGramFilters)
                            .Tokenizer("ngram_tokenizer")))
                    .Tokenizers(tz => tz
                        .NGram("ngram_tokenizer", td => td
                            .MinGram(3)
                            .MaxGram(3)
                            .TokenChars(TokenChar.Letter, TokenChar.Digit)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
    public void Index(IEnumerable<ElasticVideoMaterial> models)
    {
        foreach(var model in models)
        {
            client.Index(model,i=>i.Index(index));
        }
    }
    public void Search(string query)
    {
        var resp = client.Search<ElasticVideoMaterial>(i => i
                                                        .Query(q => q
                                                            .Match(m => m
                                                                .Field(f => f.OriginalTitle.Suffix("ngram"))
                                                                .Query("Hob")
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                        .Index(index)
                                                    ).Documents.ToList();
    }
}
```

I always create an index again, then I index the list of objects.
To do this, use the Index () method.
Here is my indexing class.

```
public class ElasticVideoMaterial
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string OriginalTitle { get; set; }
    public float? KinopoiskRating { get; set; }
    public float? Imdb { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public List<string> GenreTitles { get; set; }
    public List<string> CountryNames { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public List<string> TranslationTitles { get; set; }
    public List<string> FilmMakerNames { get; set; }
    public List<string> ActorNames { get; set; }
    public List<string> ThemeNames { get; set; }
    public CompletionField Suggest { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to get a result using the Search () method, I get 0 results.
(Having written “Hob”, I expect to receive films whose names contain “Hobbit”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngram_analyzer` is used to analyze the query input of the search request, but this analyzer is not used to analyze the `OriginalTitle` input of the index request.

You just need to configure the analyzer to be used for the `OriginalTitle` field when indexing a document, which can be specified with [attribute mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html) or [fluent mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html). For example, fluent mapping

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
    client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

var nGramFilters = new List<string> { "lowercase", "asciifolding", "nGram_filter" };

var resp = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
     .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<ElasticVideoMaterial>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.OriginalTitle)
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .Keyword(k => k
                            .Name("keyword")
                            .IgnoreAbove(256)
                        )
                        .Text(tt => tt
                            .Name("ngram")
                            .Analyzer("ngram_analyzer")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(anz => anz
                .Custom("ngram_analyzer", cc => cc
                    .Filters(nGramFilters)
                    .Tokenizer("ngram_tokenizer")))
            .Tokenizers(tz => tz
                .NGram("ngram_tokenizer", td => td
                    .MinGram(3)
                    .MaxGram(3)
                    .TokenChars(TokenChar.Letter, TokenChar.Digit)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

var searchResponse = client.Search<ElasticVideoMaterial>(i => i
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.OriginalTitle.Suffix("ngram"))
            .Query("Hob")
        )
    )
);
```

This sets up `OriginalTitle` as a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html) and creates a multi-field called `ngram` under `OriginalTitle` which will use the `ngram_analyzer` at both index time and search time for this field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I did everything as you have and the result is still 0. 
Tell me, what could I be wrong, please?

Comment: Should the analysis be performed during indexing or do I need to make a separate request?

Comment: It's possibly an issue with you analysis? Did you delete the existing index and create a new index with the above mapping? Can you edit your question to show a complete example that we can work with to find the issue?